# Generate recover email link in firebase

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

Is there any way to create custom recoverEmail link in firebase/firebase-admin?

I've checked the docs and tutorials there's none. 
Any help would be great!

Comment: What do you mean by a "recoverLink"?

Comment: sorry, recover email link. just like generateEmailVerificationLink

Comment: See https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/email-action-links

Comment: nope. it's not there

Comment: I don't understand what "recovery email" is. Firebase doesn't support such thing. There are only password reset links, email verification links and links for email sign-in. All that is described in the above document.

Comment: Please define what a "recoverEmail" link is. Recovery email link is sent when an email is changed. if nothing is changed, then there is no need for a "recoverEmail".

Comment: When creating a custom email action landing page you need to handle the follow ing modes: resetPassword, recoverEmail, verifyEmail the link listed above details the full specification. The link is generated when using password auth provider and the user changes their email address

Comment: Hey Reyn, did you ever find a solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

From my understanding there is currently no solution for this within the SDK. Instead, we took the approach of using `admin.auth().generateSignInWithEmailLink(email, actionCodeSettings)` and then replacing the `mode` within the returned `link` from `signIn` to `recoverEmail`.

```
const updatedLink = link.replace('signIn', 'recoverEmail');
```

This allowed us to customise the `auth` handler action as suggested here [Create the email action handler page](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/custom-email-handler) in the Firbase documentation.

Now we are able to call on `admin.auth().updateUser` again to reset the email to it's previous, along with update across our databases, merchant and other services. You'll also need to add the original email to a query in the `updatedLink` too.

```
const linkWithOriginalEmail = updatedLink.concat(`&email=${email}`)
```

Hope that helps and if anyone has a better solution we'd love to discuss.

Comment: This is also what I was thinking of doing. Very strange that you can [Generate Email Action Links](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/email-action-links) for all the custom email action handlers, except for the recoverEmail custom email.

Comment: Tried this and got "The action code is invalid. This can happen if the code is malformed, expired, or has already been used." when I tried to click it.

Comment: @kentcdodds Oh hey, it's the legendary kent. Did you find a solution to custom recovery remails?

Comment: Gave up. Went with magic links instead.

Answer (score 0):

I´m not sure if I understand your problem correctly, but If your goal is to have a custom link in the automatic email sent by Firebase when someone changes his authentication email address with `updateEmail` then you can define a custom action url in the Firebase console e.g. `https://example.com/__/auth/action` in the Authentication section and add the following code to the defined url (ref. https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/custom-email-handler).

```js
function handleRecoverEmail(auth, actionCode, lang) {
  // Localize the UI to the selected language as determined by the lang
  // parameter.
  var restoredEmail = null;
  // Confirm the action code is valid.
  auth.checkActionCode(actionCode).then(function(info) {
    // Get the restored email address.
    restoredEmail = info['data']['email'];

    // Revert to the old email.
    return auth.applyActionCode(actionCode);
  }).then(function() {
    // Account email reverted to restoredEmail

    // TODO: Display a confirmation message to the user.

    // You might also want to give the user the option to reset their password
    // in case the account was compromised:
    auth.sendPasswordResetEmail(restoredEmail).then(function() {
      // Password reset confirmation sent. Ask user to check their email.
    }).catch(function(error) {
      // Error encountered while sending password reset code.
    });
  }).catch(function(error) {
    // Invalid code.
  });
}
```